# Image Url to binary

Tags: java

please anyone help me to convert an image url to binary format and converted  binary to image url..Iam using java ...please reply

Comment: `image url to binary format.` ?? , are you talking about fetching image from URL ????

Comment: Your question is not clear. Image typically is stored using one of graphical formats that are binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `URLConnection` to read it into a `BufferedInputStream` or output it into a File using a `FileOutputStream`.

Sample code that demonstrates how this can be done is available at this java2.com [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/SavebinaryfilefromURL.htm)